# How i can get data from the diffrent pages and render that data into another page using shared preferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Here I have one signup flow when I filled up all the details of the first page and when I press next it will store into shared preferences and go to the next page. after filling all page and the end of the page I want to print all data using shared preferences in a flutter.

Here is full source code of project where you can get all pages with code,
https://github.com/rutvikgumasana/signup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass data in navigation from one class to another class, just have a look at below code I have made some changes

Sign Up Model class

```
  import 'dart:convert';

  SignUpModel signUpModelFromJson(String str) => SignUpModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String signUpModelToJson(SignUpModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

  class SignUpModel {
 String businessLegalName;
 int businessPhoneNo;
 int businessYear;

 SignUpModel({
   this.businessLegalName,
   this.businessPhoneNo,
   this.businessYear,
 });

 factory SignUpModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SignUpModel(
      businessLegalName: json["business_legal_name"] == null ? null :    json["business_legal_name"],
      businessPhoneNo: json["business_phone_no"] == null ? null : json["business_phone_no"],
      businessYear: json["business_year"] == null ? null : json["business_year"],
    );

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   "business_legal_name": businessLegalName == null ? null : businessLegalName,
   "business_phone_no": businessPhoneNo == null ? null : businessPhoneNo,
   "business_year": businessYear == null ? null : businessYear,
 };
  }
```

changes in BspSignupPage class

```
SignUpModel model = SignUpModel();
                  model.businessLegalName = clrbusinessname.text;
                  model.businessPhoneNo = clrphone.text as int;
                  model.businessYear = clrestablishedyear.text as int;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BspUnlicensedSignupPage(
                        signUpModel: model,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
```

changes in BspUnlicensedSignupPage

```
class BspUnlicensedSignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspUnlicensedSignup";
  final SignUpModel signUpModel;

  BspUnlicensedSignupPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.signUpModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BspUnlicensedSignupPageState createState() =>
      _BspUnlicensedSignupPageState();
}
```

and in init state method

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('Page1 Data: ${widget.signUpModel.businessLegalName}');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use only one page instead and use `PageView` or `IndexedStack` for this purpose. 
Using `IndexedStack`, you can show only one child widget at a time and switch the current index on button click. But in this case you have to create the animation yourself as `IndexedStack` don't provide default animation.

If you use `PageView`, you have default animation and can also switch it on button click.
It provides you swipe gesture as well which can be disabled using

> PageView(physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())

Answer (score 0):

Try This, 
Create one Object class(POJO Class) and store the data in shared preference, whenever user click next/ submit button. And then, once you reach to final screen get the data from preference and show.